# scrapy gives 500 Internal Server error while trying to load nepalstock.com

Tags: python, scrapy

when i try to load the url `http://nepalstock.com/todaysprice` into scrapy shell it return a 500 internal server error . Any reason why this site in particular would throw such an error ?

I have already tried to load other sites and all of them load fine in the shell . I also have tried to execute them with and without http .

```
scrapy shell 'http://nepalstock.com'

2019-04-07 12:09:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-07 12:09:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-07 12:09:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://nepalstock.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://nepalstock.com> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2019-04-07 12:09:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://nepalstock.com> (referer: None)
```

Comment: More generally, "500 Internal Server Error" can simply mean that there is an error on the server, and probably nothing you can do about it. Maybe try a slightly different URL in case it's something you said which upset the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any reason why this site in particular would throw such an error ?

The `User-Agent` header.

Many sites will respond with errors to requests with user-agents commonly used by bots. 
[Scrapy's default user agent](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) is `Scrapy/VERSION (+https://scrapy.org)`, but you can set another value for it.

```py
$ scrapy shell
...
>>> req = scrapy.Request( 
    'http://nepalstock.com/todaysprice', 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0'}, 
)                                                                                                                                                      
>>> fetch(req)                                                                                                                                         
2019-04-07 12:08:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://nepalstock.com/todaysprice> (referer: None)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much . It worked  
>>> req
<GET http://nepalstock.com/todaysprice>  and i was able to access the page using response object .